# jQuery validate: submitting form only when fields are validated

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, jquery-validate, form-submit

I'm using the code below to validate my form. The validation is going great but I have a problem when submitting the form. And the problem is: the form is submitted to the php file everytime the "Send form" button is clicked, no matter if the form is not validated.

How can I fix that?

I've been researching submitHandler but I don't know how to use it with ajax and serialize..

Thanks a lot!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form").validate({
      rules: {
         name: {
           required: true
         },
         lname: {
           required: true
         }

      },
      messages: {
         name: {
           required: "* required"
         },
         lname: {
           required: "* required"
         }
      }

   }); //end validate

  $('#form').submit(function() {

    theUrl = 'form.php';

     var params = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: theUrl,
            data: params,
            processData:false,
            async:false,
            success: function(result) {

                //if (data != "") alert (data);
            }
    });
    //return false;
  }); //end submit

});    //end document ready 



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your AJAX request code in the `submitHandler` parameter of the validate plugin. Currently the AJAX request is being run on the `submit()` event, parrallel to any validation result. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: { required: true },
            lname: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            name: { required: "* required" },
            lname: { required: "* required" }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            theUrl = 'form.php';
            var params = $(form).serialize();

            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: theUrl,
                data: params,
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    //if (data != "") alert (data);
                }
            });
        }
    }); //end validate
});
```

[More information on the `submitHandler` parameter.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)