# jQuery validation: some of the required field not filled but the form can still be submitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I used jquery validation (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for form validation. The followings are some fragments of my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="formID" action="/processForm" method="post">
  ...
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" size="10" />
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" size="10" />
  ...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#formID").validate({
  onkeyup:false,

  rules: {
    name: {required: true},
    username: {required: true, checkUsername: true}
    ...
  },
  messages: {
    name: {required: "Must fill"},
    username: {required: "Must fill", checkUsername: "Username unavailable"},
    ...
  }

});

// Check if username exists
$.validator.addMethod('checkUsername', function(username) {
  var postURL = "/checkUsername";
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
  return ...;
}, '');


// Submit the form by Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formID').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#content').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
```

Something odd is that I can leave some of the required fields blank or unchecked, and the form can still be submitted. Some required fields can prevent from submitting if left blank, but others don't. Did anybody encounter the same strange problem? Or did I do anything wrong here?

BTW, if I click the submit button without filling anything, all required fields show error messages correctly. But some of them just won't prevent the form from been submitted. Please help.

EDIT:
The Ajax form submission function at the bottom doesn't seem to work. How do I correct it?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle example tha shows the problem you're having? Also, don't just rely on client-side validation. You have to validate on the server as well, because anything coming from a user cannot be trusted, even if they are in a trusted environment (school, office, etc)

Comment: `$("#addMemberSubmitForm").validate({` don't you need to place the form ID there?, so it should be `$("#formID").validate({`

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo.

Comment: @Ashley Sheridan: I am developing my programs on Google App Engine, and they are rather complicated. I ran the page of my program and the jsfiddle just gave me a 404 and they are truly sorry because there was no such page.

Comment: I found the problem: I missed implementing one of the customized methods. How embarrassing ... Sorry guys. But the final question is still valid: by using validate() function, my form now isn't submitted by the Ajax function. How do I submit the form with Ajax? Thanks and sorry again.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321692/jquery-validation-conflicts-with-ajax-form-submission/14324860#14324860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up, in order to employ both form validation and ajax submission, add 'submitHandler' to the validate() function:

```
$("#formID").validate({
  onkeyup:false,

  rules: {
    ...
  },

  messages: {
    ...
  },

  // Submit the form
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    theUrl = '/processData';
    var params = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax ({
      type: "POST",
      url: theUrl,
      data: params,
      processData: false,
      async: false,
      success: function(returnData) {
        $('#content').html(returnData);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what I did is:
1) change the the submit button :
     from :

```
<input type="submit" class="savebutton" id="save" value="Save" />

to

 <input type="button" class="savebutton" id="save" value="Save" />  

(the save button is not going to submit the form when is click it).
```

2)change my validation script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#form').validate({ 
     rules: {
         qty: {
    max: 100,
            required: true
         }
    },
    messages: {
        qty: "please check quantity",
    }
});

 $( "#save" ).click(function() {
if ($('#form').validate())$('#form').submit();
 });
});
</script>
```

when the "save" button is hit, it validates the form. if the validation is correct, then it's going to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
// Submit the form by Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formID').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#content').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
```

Use the `submitHandler` option of the [Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) plugin, like this:

```
$("#formID").validate({
    //all your other options
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).ajaxForm({
        success: function(returnData) {
          $('#content').html(returnData);
        }
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but when I clicked the "Submit" button, there was no action, except two of my customized method got executed (/checkUsername and the other). What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I changed $(form).ajaxForm to form.ajaxForm, and the form is able to be submitted. However, the returned data is not inserted into "content" div. What could be the problem?

Comment: Hey, when I changes the submitHandler function to what is described in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8383774/1802305, everything worked just fine. Ryley, would you be so kind to explain why? I am really curious. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yuan-LiangTang, probably because you were trying to use two different plugins to intercept the same form `submit` event.  As per [the jQuery Form plugin page](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq), _"`ajaxSubmit` submits the form, `ajaxForm` does not."_  You might as well not rely on another plugin to do the Ajax... it's simple enough on its own, as you discovered.  Please post your solution as another answer so as to help other people reading this.