# jQuery validation conflicts with Ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery validation: some of the required field not filled but the form can still be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319857/jquery-validation-some-of-the-required-field-not-filled-but-the-form-can-still)

I used jquery validation (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for form validation:

HTML:

```
<form id="formID" action="/processForm" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#formID").validate({
  onkeyup:false,
  rules: {
    ...
  },
  messages: {
    ...
  }
});


// Submit the form by Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formID').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#content').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
```

Now the form seems to be submitted by the validate() function, not by the Ajax function.

How do I still use the Ajax function?

Comment: Just a quick note: `$('.formID').ajaxForm()` should be `$('#formID').ajaxForm()` your ajax is acting on the form with class 'formID'

Answer (score 1):

> Now the form seems to be submitted by the `validate()` function, not by
>   the Ajax function. How do I still use the Ajax function?

That's because the `validate()` plugin already has a `submitHandler:` built-in.  Here's how to use it properly and avoid potential conflicts between multiple functions acting on the same `submit` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#formID").validate({
      onkeyup:false,
      rules: {
        ...
      },
      messages: {
        ...
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.ajaxForm({
              success: function(returnData) {
                  $('#content').html(returnData);
              }
          });
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this JS:

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function(){

// call your function which send AJAX  reuest
// Or code of sending ajax reauest

return false;

})
```